# Mitzvah of hachnasat orchim at a B&B

Tags: travel, business, hachnasat-orchim-guests

Does someone who owns a bed-and-breakfast ([*tzimmer*](http://www.balashon.com/2006/06/tzimmer.html)) fulfill the mitzvah of *hachnasat orchim* when their guests pay them?

On the one hand, the hosts get clear monetary benefit from hosting. However, they are still opening up their home (or a room of it) and letting people stay.

This question was inspired by someone who owns a B&B mentioning that it almost felt weird to do *hachnasat orchim* without getting paid for it. Seemingly, this person at least feels like they fulfill the mitzvah to some extent when being payed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [Rabbi Chaim Ehrman](http://www.cckollel.org/html/parsha/bereishis/vayera-2002.html) from the Chicago Community Kollel based on a Maharsham there are Poskim that say that since Hachnosas Orchim is a Mitzva therefore one may accept payment for one staying over Shabbos. However Rabbi Moshe Shternbuch in [Teshuvos V'hanhogos 2:197](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=162) disagrees and says that one does not do the Mitzva of Hachnosas Orchim when paid.

> Does a person fulfill the mitzvah of Hachnosas Orchim if he is being
>   paid for it? There is a discussion in the Poskim regarding paying or
>   accepting pay for a hotel stay on Shabbos. The issue surrounds the
>   halacha that one is not allowed to pay for or accept payment for work
>   or services done on Shabbos. The Maharsham writes [O.H. 306-4] that
>   perhaps since Hachnosas Orchim is a mitzvah, it would be permitted to
>   pay or accept payment, as found in similar cases of other mitzvos. The
>   poskim infer from here that the Maharsham would hold that even if one
>   accepts payment, he would still fulfill this mitzvah. HaGaon Rav Moshe
>   Shternbuch shlita [Teshuvos V’Hanhagos Volume 2:197] strongly
>   disagrees and is of the opinion that if one accepts money, he would
>   not fulfill the mitzvah of Hachnosas Orchim. The Magen Avrohom [O.H.
>   38:8] rules that if one’s main intent was to fulfill the mitzvah, and
>   the payment was secondary, then he would have fulfilled the mitzvah.
>   The Biur Halachah extends this even further, saying that even if a
>   person’s intentions were equally weighted, that would be sufficient to
>   fulfill the mitzvah.

Comment: Interesting answer to an interesting question. He seems to imply a general rule that one may pay for a mitzvah on Shabbat, am I understanding this correctly? If so, is this related to allowing shuls to ask for monetary donations for aliyot and run appeals on Shabbat, or is this a separate idea?

Comment: @DanF: I think you hit the nail on the head and it is related.

Comment: Thanks, I may ask a question about this. Offhand, mixing money ideas with a mitzvah sounds like a violation of "Daber Davar", no?

Comment: @DanF: Daber Davar is a problem on Shabbos. Here the fellow is paying before or after - for the Shabbos stay. On Shabbos there is no discussion regarding the payment.

Comment: @DanF חפציך אסורים ולא חפצי שמים